# injecting a bean as a value to a property of another bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf, dependency-injection

How would some inject a bean as a value to a property of another bean?

For example

```
        public class FileNameGenerator
    {
        private String name;
        private String type;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

<bean id="FileNameGenerator" class="FileNameGenerator">
        <property name="name">
            <value>value1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="type">
            <value>value2</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Instead I am trying to inject a factory method bean in value1

```
<bean id="FileNameGenerator" class="FileNameGenerator">
                <property name="name">
                    <value>
<bean class="SomeOtherClass" factory-method="staticMethodThatReturnsString">
</value>
                </property>
                <property name="type">
                    <value>value2</value>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need use SpEL :

```
   <bean id="FileNameGenerator" class="org....path....FileNameGenerator">
      <property name="name">
         <value>#{T(org....path....SomeOtherClass).staticMethodThatReturnsString()}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="type">
         <value>value2</value>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

us factory-method for getting class that you know in advance , it's bad practice . You know that you need String and you know how to get it from some static method - but method that return String it's not facory. with spel just call that static method for  field `name`. In your case use factory method it is overuse

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **value** tag around your factory-bean.

Your code should look like this:

```
<bean id="FileNameGenerator" class="FileNameGenerator">
    <property name="name">
        <bean class="SomeOtherClass" factory-method="staticMethodThatReturnsString">
    </property>
    <property name="type">
        <value>value2</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```